# How can I increase CPU/RAM available to VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Was playing around with some larger data sets and noticed that VSCode only uses around 30% CPU and RAM.
Is there some way to increase it? Probably some configurations? Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You can increase/decrease the available RAM for VS Code on its Settings. Go to File -> Preferences -> Settings, there you can type `files.maxMemoryForLargeFilesMB` and change the value for your desired maximum RAM.

Comment: Ex.
```"files.maxMemoryForLargeFilesMB": 16384```

Comment: Not sure if VSCODE changed but I'm getting: "Unknown Configuration Setting"

Comment: may be this option is removed https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/175792#issuecomment-1573347906

Answer (score -2):

Not sure which coding language are you using, but let's break your question in two parts:

> **How to use more CPU ? (Can Increase Performance)**

1. By using multiprocessing apis, which can divide a given large data sets into smaller units to be processed by various CPU cores, it is like a master slave architecture, where each sub process will execute on separate core and at max it is driven by total number of CPU cores.
2. If number of data units is more than CPU cores, then it will context switch

> **How to use more RAM ? (Can Degrade Performance)**

1. Why do you need to increase RAM usage, that will be anyway dependant on amount of data allocated by the program
2. You may plan to create multiple copies to have a snapshot for each thread, needn't then use mutex or lock, but generally not a good practice

> **Finally :**

1. CPU and RAM will be used process that is executing, based on programming langiage not the VSCode which is just an editor